# How do you get out of Dead Man's Respite?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I went to the Bard's college to see what that was all about, and I went to Dead Mans Respite. I got the book but I don't know how to get out..

Anyone know if this is a glitch, or im supposed to do something?
I should also mention im on PS3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you enter Dead Mans Respite you are welcomed by a ghost bard that presumably wrote Olaf's verse. When you follow the bard through the dungeon he will lead you up to a sealed door and will go to the right of that door, eventually you will find the book. Now, walk back to the sealed door.

> The bard will greet you again and will break the magical seal on the door.
>  You will see a short scene where the bard will challenge King Olaf; a fight will commence.

After this, there will be a backdoor out which you will need to activate through a chain on the wall, tracing back to the entrance tomb of the dungeon.

Comment: Go back to where you got the book. Walk up the stairs and take a right. That's the door that used to be blue and unopenable. Now it's not blue and openable.